# How to show A child window from MainViewModel based on some Property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

Hi I have a situation where I have to show a Window "Connection Window", based on some condition. I am using PRISM 6.0 and WPF, C#. enter image description here
[image]

I have a Main Window as described in the picture associated with MainWindowViewModle and a Connection Window. Now first I will click on the connect Button and this Connect window will appear. This window and its view Model "ConnectionWindowViewModel" will do the rest of the connection process. If the connection is successful the ConnectWindowViewModel notify that to the MainWindowViewModel through eventAggregaor like

```
In ConnectionViewModel
    _eventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdateConnectionEvent>().Publish(connection);

In MainWindowViewModel
    eventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdateConnectionEvent>().Subscribe(UpdateConnectionSettings);
```

The Content of the Button will change to `Disconnect` and the connection Window will disappear automatically.

Now if I want to disconnect this connection, disconnection should be done from the `MainWindowViewModel` and the connect window shouldn't appear.

After successful disconnection The Content of the button should be changed to `"Connect"`. and again the same process repeats.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You have the same post from several hours ago that was marked as duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163738/show-a-window-based-on-some-condition-from-viewmodel. What gives?

Comment: My question is described in the Question part "How can I show the Connect window based n some property on the `MainWindowViewModel`? After `Connect` Button is clicked I have to show the Connect Window, but after the same button (`Disconnect`) is clicked I don't want to show the `Connect Window` but I will do the Disconnection process.

Comment: Why not have a command bound to your button that does the logic you want? If in "not connected" state, show the connect window when clicked, change the button text to "disconnect" if connection is established, close the connection when clicked if in "connected" state...

Comment: Why this question is Down voted? is it doesn't worth to be a quality question in the SO? Amazing ... just amazing!!!

Answer (score 1):

My approach to this would be to use the [Interaction Request](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/WPF/45-AdvancedMVVMScenarios.md#using-interaction-request-objects) objects that are built into Prism. With these you can open a dialog (an interaction) that can be used to prompt the end use for information, like user name and password. There is a small sample in the Prism [documentation](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/WPF/45-AdvancedMVVMScenarios.md#using-interaction-request-objects), and there is a more involved sample on the [Prism GitHub repo](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/InteractivityQuickstart/InteractivityQuickstart).

Using these techniques, and a Connected property on the main window view model to indicate the state of the connection, you should be able to accomplish this quite easily. I use Interaction Requests a fair amount, they work well for simple (confirmation of a change) and complex scenarios (edit/property dialogs).